# in LUA....Corona SDK... My new score is Overlapping without erasing old score?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

in code below it displays "SCORE: 100" or whatever however as the score / points change
the totals are over lapping one on top of the other and you cant read them ...
i want the old score erased / removed before displaying new score/points
ANY THOUGHTS HOW TO FIX this...this is LUA and using CORONA SDK
during my test i have sent print statements to try to troubleshoot sections

--Points is being calculated in another location 
    --UPDATE SCORE POINTS

```
local function updateScore(Points)

  if WTF == 1 then
    print ("SCORE: -->",Points)

    --PointsText:removeSelf(PointsText)

        PointsText = display.newText(Points,0,0,native.sytemFont,42)        
        PointsText.text = Points
        PointsText.xscale = 0.5; PointsText.yscale = 0.5
        PointsText:setTextColor(155,155,225)
        PointsText.x = centerX * 1
        PointsText.y = centerY - 150

        ScoreTxt = display.newText("Score: ",0,0,native.systemFont,40) 
        ScoreTxt:setTextColor(220,50,50)
        ScoreTxt.x = display.contentCenterX
        ScoreTxt.y = display.contentCenterY-100
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call updateScore you're creating a new text object. This code ensures you only create the text once.

```
local function updateScore(Points)
    if PointsText == nil then
        PointsText = display.newText(Points,0,0,native.sytemFont,42)        
    end

    PointsText.text = Points
    PointsText.xscale = 0.5; PointsText.yscale = 0.5
    PointsText:setTextColor(155,155,225)
    PointsText.x = centerX * 1
    PointsText.y = centerY - 150

    ScoreTxt = display.newText("Score: ",0,0,native.systemFont,40) 
    ScoreTxt:setTextColor(220,50,50)
    ScoreTxt.x = display.contentCenterX
    ScoreTxt.y = display.contentCenterY-100
end
```

You could also do:

```
local function updateScore(Points)
    if PointsText then
        PointsText:removeSelf()     
    end

    PointsText = display.newText(Points,0,0,native.systemFont,42)        
    PointsText.text = Points
    PointsText.xscale = 0.5; PointsText.yscale = 0.5
    PointsText:setTextColor(155,155,225)
    PointsText.x = centerX * 1
    PointsText.y = centerY - 150

    ScoreTxt = display.newText("Score: ",0,0,native.systemFont,40) 
    ScoreTxt:setTextColor(220,50,50)
    ScoreTxt.x = display.contentCenterX
    ScoreTxt.y = display.contentCenterY-100
end
```

Comment: Have you tried the code I posted? It allow you to change the score text's value so you don't get overlapping text objects. Also see my edit.

Comment: THANK  YOU.....THANK   YOU       THANK    YOU.... i have been trying forever.....thank god for you and STACKOVERFLOW.COM

Comment: @user2975358 accept his answer if you really want to thank him